# download entire folder from a storage service (firebase, S3,....) with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, amazon-s3

I have a React app where I need to upload files (pdf files for example), and store them under *distinctive* folders,

What I need to know, is if there is a way to download or get download link for an entire **folder** X,

I tried with **firebase**, but it only offers to get link of a **single** file at a time, not full folder, does S3, or something else have this option?

Thanks.